# Why is GetHashCode() method compiled differently for DateTime compared to other structs?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Consider the following methods in C#:

```
public static int HashCodeFunction(Decimal value)
{
    return value.GetHashCode();
}
public static int HashCodeFunction(Int64 value)
{
    return value.GetHashCode();
}
public static int HashCodeFunction(DateTime value)
{
    return value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Let's look at the instructions generated by the compiler:

For the `Decimal` method:

```
ldarga.s Parameter:System.Decimal value
call Method:System.Decimal.GetHashCode()
ret
```

For the `Int64` method:

```
ldarga.s Parameter:System.Int64 value
call Method:System.Int64.GetHashCode()
ret
```

For the `DateTime` method:

```
ldarga.s Parameter:System.DateTime value
constrained Type:System.DateTime
callvirt Method:System.Object.GetHashCode()
ret
```

Why is the `DateTime.GetHashCode()` method being treated as a virtual call of `Object.GetHashCode()`, considering there is an overridden `GetHashCode()` method for the `DateTime` struct?

Furthermore, I can create a method that directly calls the `System.DateTime.GetHashCode()` method without the virtual call using the following code:

```
DynamicMethod myDynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("myHashCodeMethod", typeof(int), new[] { typeof(DateTime) });

ILGenerator gen = myDynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
LocalBuilder local = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(DateTime));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, local);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("GetHashCode"));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Then create a delegate to test it:

```
Func<DateTime, int> myNewHashCodeFunction = (Func<DateTime,int>)myDynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<DateTime, int>));

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

int myHashCode = myNewHashCodeFunction(dt);
int theirHashCode = dt.GetHashCode();
// These values are the same.
```

Just curious why the method is implemented this way by default for `Int64` and `Decimal`, but not `DateTime`.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, I don't see any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to Roslyn, what you're describing is an old behavior (Roslyn version 1.1.0 and older). The new behavior (version 1.2.0 and newer) is to use `call` for `DateTime` too.

The change was made in [pull request *String concat with char and similar primitives should call overriden ToString directly* (#7080)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/7080).

The problem with the `constrained.callvirt` → `call` optimization is that it means removing the override becomes a binary breaking change, so the optimization can't be applied universally. But it can be applied to types where the compiler can be sure that the override is not going to be removed.

The old behavior was to use this optimization for "intrinsic types" (those that have keywords in C#) and some special rarely used types. The new behavior is to use the optimization for all "special types", which include intrinsic types and also `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

I tested your code on my machine, all three methods emit `call` instead of `callvirt`, so I guess this could be compiler-specific.

My guess is, earlier version of Csc emits `call` only for [simple type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) virtual methods, so it was actually these simple types made special, not `DateTime`. Later, they decided that it's worth nothing to emit `callvirt` for value type method calls, as they would never be overridden. So all value type method calls are emitted with `call`, while reference type virtual method calls with `callvirt`.

PS. I have Visual Studio 2015 with .NET Framework 4.6.1 on my machine. I tested with .NET 2.0 to 4.6.1, all of them generates the same IL code (no `callvirt` for `DateTime.GetHashCode`).

Comment: I get the `callvirt` when I compile with LINQPad 5 or Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.0.0 (which seems to be what LINQPad is using). This seems to have changed in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.2.0.